# Reading InputStream from a batch file's process skips to next line

Tags: java, windows, process, batch-file, inputstream

I am trying to run a batch file with Runtime.exec() and then output its InputStream into a JTextArea. What I have works, but only partially. What happens is the batch file runs, but if it executes a command other than something like "echo" that command immediately terminates and the next line executes. For example, let's say I try to run a simple batch file like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello. waiting 5 seconds.
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
echo finished. goodbye.
```

The batch file executes, and the JTextArea says

```
hello. waiting 5 seconds.
finished. goodbye.
```

but it doesn't wait for 5 seconds in the middle.

I can't figure out why it's doing this. Here's what I use to run the batch file and read its InputStream.

```
private class ScriptRunner implements Runnable {
private final GUI.InfoGUI gui; // the name of my GUI class
private final String script;

public ScriptRunner(final GUI.InfoGUI gui, final File script) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.script = script.getAbsolutePath();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
        StreamReader output = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream(), gui);
        Thread t = new Thread(output);
        t.start();
        int exit = p.waitFor();
        output.setComplete(true);
        while (t.isAlive()) {
            sleep(500);
        }
        System.out.println("Processed finished with exit code " + exit);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
private class StreamReader implements Runnable {
private final InputStream is;
private final GUI.InfoGUI gui;

private boolean complete = false;

public StreamReader(InputStream is, GUI.InfoGUI gui) {
    this.is = is;
    this.gui = gui;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while (!complete || in.ready()) {
            while (in.ready()) {
                gui.setTextAreaText(in.readLine() + "\n");
            }
            sleep(250);
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setComplete(final boolean complete) {
    this.complete = complete;
}

}
public void sleep(final long ms) {
try {
    Thread.sleep(ms);
} catch (final InterruptedException ie) {
}
}
```

I know my code is pretty messy, and I'm sure it contains grammatical errors.

Thanks for anything you can do to help!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a `Process` but you're not reading from its standard error stream.  The process might be writing messages to its standard error to tell you that there's a problem, but if you're not reading its standard error, you won't be able to read these messages.

You have two options here:

1. Since you already have a class that reads from a stream (`StreamReader`), wire up another one of these to the process's standard error stream (`p.getErrorStream()`) and run it in another `Thread`.  You'll also need to  call `setComplete` on the error StreamReader when the call to `p.waitFor()` returns, and wait for the Thread running it to die.
2. Replace your use of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` with a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  This class is new in Java 5 and provides an alternative way to run external processes.  In my opinion its most significant improvement over `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is the ability to redirect the process's standard error into its standard output, so you only have one stream to read from.

I would strongly recommend going for the second option and choosing to redirect the process's standard error into its standard output.

I took your code and replaced the line

```
        final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
```

with

```
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(script);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, I don't have your GUI code to hand, so I wrote the output of the process to `System.out` instead.

When I ran your code, I got the following output:

```
hello. waiting 5 seconds.
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.
finished. goodbye.
Processed finished with exit code 0
```

Had you seen that error message, you might have twigged that something was up with the `timeout` command.

Incidentally, I noticed in one of your comments that none of the commands suggested by ughzan worked.  I replaced the `timeout` line with `ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL` and the script ran as expected.  I couldn't reproduce a problem with this.

Comment: oh! I had tried creating another StreamReader that reads the process' error stream and I received the same message! I just looked over the message and thought it meant that you can't ever read from a batch file's error stream, not from timeout... I guess that makes more sense though.

Thanks helping out. However I'm still at a loss for a final solution . What I'm mainly doing in the batch files is using adb shell to run certain commands on a connected Android device... if the problem is in the commands, then what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: also, about ping working/not working... sorry, that was my mistake. I've been working on this problem for a couple days and once I changed the batch file to both timeout and ping things and it skipped the timeout, but I remembered incorrectly and thought that ping also was terminating early... sorry about that.

Comment: I was searching for a solution to the same error in my Delphi code when writing code for launching a console application and redirecting its output to my application.  The batch file that I was testing also had a TIMEOUT /T call which was giving the same error. The problem was in the code that calls CreateProcess - you must ensure that your STARTUP_INFO's hStdInput is 0. In my case, this was a pipe's read handle. I don't know Java and this problem is likely to be in the underlying classes that you're using, so doubt this is of much help, but FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is definitely in `timeout.exe`. If you add `echo %errorlevel%` after line with `timeout`, you will see that it returns `1` if running from java. And `0` if running in usual way. Probably, it requires some specific console functionality (i.e. cursor positioning) that is suppressed when running from java process.

> Is there anything I can do to get this to work while running from Java

If you don't need ability to run *any* batch file then consider to replace `timeout` with `ping`. Otherwise... I've tried to run batch file with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/#readme) trough `Kernel32.CreateProcess` and `timeout` runs fine. But then you need to implement reading of process output trough native calls also.

I hope someone will suggest better way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You're correct; the errorlevel is 1 from java but 0 from a command prompt. Is there anything I can do to get this to work while running from Java?

Answer (score 1):

The `ready` method only tells if the stream can guarantee that something can be read immediately, without blocking. You can't really trust it because always returning `false` is a valid implementation. Streams with buffers may return `true` only when they have something buffered. So I suspect your problem is here:

```
    while (!complete || in.ready()) {
        while (in.ready()) {
            gui.setTextAreaText(in.readLine() + "\n");
        }
        sleep(250);
    }
```

It should rather read something like this:

```
    String line;
    while (!complete || (line=in.readLine()) != null) {
        gui.setTextAreaText(line + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your "timeout ..." command returned with an error.

Three ways to test it:

1. Check if the "timeout ..." command works in the Windows command prompt.
2. Replace "timeout ..." in the script with "ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL" (it essentially does the same thing)
3. Remove everything but "timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL" from your script. The process should return with an error (1) if the timeout failed because it is the last command executed.

Comment: All the different commands I try will still return error 1. What can I do, besides running "cmd /c file.bat"?